# Is there a javagent equivalent for Mono?

Tags: mono, instrumentation, agent

1.5+ JVMs have a [`-javaagent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) switch, which enable load-time instrumentation of byte codes. This is used by tools like [Byteman](http://www.jboss.org/byteman) to inject tracing code into Java byte codes as it is loaded by the JVM.

Is there an equivalent for the Mono CLR?

Answer (score 0):

For tracing you can use the [profiler hooks](http://monotorrent.blogspot.com/2010/12/writing-profiler-for-mono.html). Actual instrumentation at load time is not something I'd recommend, mostly because for signed assemblies, modifying them breaks their verifiability.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the profile hook! I don't know much about the CLR, but my guess is that once a signed assembly is verified the CLR will load it - it is at this load-time that I want to hook into.

Comment: The signing process is, among other things, meant to prevent tampering. Thus by design it should not be possible to circumvent it by modifying an assembly after it had been verified.

Comment: That is strange; I was under the impression that signing process it to ensure that the software you are about to run on *your machine* is the one that the developer published -- and that some third-party had not tampered with it. If I have an assembly, signed or not, I can always create an interpreter to execute the code in whatever way I feel fit (provided it is *legally* permissible). Again, I don't have any experience with the .NET world; but the model you described does not quite make sense to me.

Comment: Well the _third party_ could be another plugin loaded by the same application - signing is also meant to prevent such attack scenarios. However, Mono did not actually enforce strong name signature correctness last time I checked (this might have changed when Moonlight security model was implemented). Even if the signatures are validated, nothing is stopping you from disabling this mechanism.

Comment: On the windows platform you can use the ICorProfilerCallback interface etc to add instrumentation to signed assemblies.